# Spinner: getItemAtPosition(position) is returning always null/empty

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I wanted to display selected item in the `textView` when selected from dropdown list of spinner I implemented `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` but when I'm selecting item its always `null/empty` here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, Languages));

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                        View view, int position, long id) {

    item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

Comment: share error logcat

Comment: No Error in android logcat

Comment: i am create costume spinner try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159011/spinner-item-is-not-visible-data-is-coming-from-server-android/45161202#45161202

Comment: Is the adapter null? Try getting the item from the List on the basis of position rather than adapter

Comment: post class `CustomAdapter` code and check if `Object CustomAdapter#getItem(int position)` returns `null`

Comment: yes it returning null

Comment: so you have your answer

Comment: yeah sure, actually I'm trying to understand adapter there is no much information about this and i this was first time i was implementing spinner adapter

Comment: Thank you for pointing out :) you may post answer so i can accept

Comment: then return the item that is pointed by given`position`

Comment: The people like you are legends :)

Comment: For explanation, `AdapterView#getItemAtPosition` just call `Adapter#getItem`. It will return `null` if adapter is null, invalid position or `getItem` return null. `getItem` will return the object at a specific position in your dataset of your adapter.

Comment: yeah, tell it to my boss...

Comment: @Càphêđen solved

Comment: @pskink yeah sure, details please

Answer (score 1):

SO answer source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49301966/5461982

I know this is an older question now but if anyone else comes across it be sure to check that your custom implementation of the Adapter you're setting for your Spinner overrides the `getItem` method:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return spinnerItems.get(position);
}
```

By default, you're required to override this method when implementing a custom `BaseAdapter` but the default return type is `null`. Be sure to modify the return type to `return spinnerItems.get(position)`.

Hope this helps, I spent around 30 mins trying to work this out originally!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String selected_item = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: String str= String.valueOf(yourSpinner.getItemAtPosition(position));

Comment: for this application crashed when first run: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: which means spinner don't have array items. kindly check whether spinner array items or not

Comment: check `Languages` array. i suspecting that array is null.

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve value from String Array:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final String item = Languages[position];
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            sSelectedItem = arr_spiner.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition())
                    .getName();
            txtSpinnerValue.setText(sSelectedItem);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159011/spinner-item-is-not-visible-data-is-coming-from-server-android/45161202#45161202
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, Languages));

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                        View view, int position, long id) {

    //item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
      item = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(); //Here is the Change

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

**The change here is**

From

```
item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

TO

```
item = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: didn't make any difference